# How to override Breadcrumb theme template?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, breadcrumbs

I have a custom theme that has `base theme: classy` setting in the `mytheme.info.yml` file. When we enable twig debugging locally, we find that the `<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/mytheme/templates/navigation/breadcrumb.html.twig' -->` is displayed, but there are no theme suggestions available.

This is what displayed on the page.

[image]

**How can we create theme suggestions for breadcrumbs?**

We tried the following in the `mytheme.theme` file, but it did not print out the `ksm()` statements.

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_breadcrumb_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  ksm($suggestions); // this returns empty
  ksm($variables); // this only returns theme_hook_suggestion and links array
}
```

The code is based off of what we can do for block suggestions alters.

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->bundle();
  }
}
```

Comment: By default `$suggestions` because there is no other suggestion, if you want another suggestions just add them to `$suggestions`

Comment: @berramou the problem is that normally i would be able to get the machine name of the entity (i.e. mybreadcreamb), but I can't get that from `$variables`

Comment: Breadcrumbs aren’t entities - what entity are you hoping to get a reference to in the theme suggestions hook?

Comment: as @Clive said breadcrumbs aren’t entities, can you update your question, which suggestion you want to add to breadcrumb ?

Comment: @Clive I was hoping to do something similar to what can be done with [blocks](https://gist.github.com/markconroy/9daa7cc8ee95cbd87e19aef181afefb2)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Clive, breadcrumbs are not entities so I was not be able to get it done by adding a `mytheme_theme_suggestions_breadcrumb_alter`. Instead to solve the problem I had to do the following. On top of this, I ended up downloading and enabling [Easy Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/easy-breadcrumb) to further modify the `Breadcrumb`

1. Copy the `breadcrumb.html.twig` file from the `Classy` theme into my `mytheme` directory
2. Clear cache
3. make any edits into the `sites/themes/custom/mytheme/templates/navigation/breadcrumb.html.twig` file
4. save and clear cache (if necessary)